# Timebased events database (approach)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I have a general question, not about some code. So I am just asking for a general approach.

In my game I have some time based events like in common applications as for example Clash of Clans. The user has the option to improve the skills of a character. Let's say that character "John" has an attack level of 1. To reach the next level which is 2, it needs 1 day for training.

Now my question is, how can I achieve this. I don't want to handle this client side with a simple countdown because the risk is too high that he can manipulate the timer. I would like to store it somewhere online and the client is requesting to the server on how much time is left.

What would be the best way?

- I know that there are timebased events in MySQL, so that I could simply run a task every 5 seconds but I think that this is not the best way.

**Edit:**

The problem I have is that if John starts his training, there has to be a countdown on the client side. But this countdown should not receive the remaining time clientside. The application should get the time from a server.

With that fact it is not very difficult, because I only need to make a request to the server getting the time when the event was triggered and calculate the remaining time with the now().

But I also want to build a live database. Where for example user "Marc" can visit the profile of John. If the time has ellapsed there should be level 2 inside the profile of John. But if John hasn't logged in there is no request to the server so that it doesn't update the level.

So the main problem is that on the one hand I can update the database records if the user logs in by simply making a post request and updating the elapsed trainings. But if the John doesn't login and Marc wants to see his level inside his profile, then there was no post request and it is showing up level 1 instead of level 2.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean *calendar* time, there are a variety of ways.  The most important component is to store the time when the state change takes place.  Don't store it as "1 day", store it as a specific date and time.

Then, you have basically three choices.

The first is to build the time into the logic of the application.  Set the level 2 time to the level 1 time plus one day.  Then determine the level using `now()`.  This has the downside that the logic can get complicated.  But for a simple example such as your question, it might be the right choice.

A second method is to generate an event for each state change and schedule it at the appropriate time.  This works when things are going at a leisurely pace, but scales really poorly.  Having to deal with managing events and other queries for performance is challenging.

The third method is a scheduled job that runs, say, once per hour.  This can make all the necessary state changes in one fell swoop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I missed some details in my question. Can you look on my edit? If you don't get what I mean, then write me that is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer for your problem. But i think i have an use case for your application.

Level of a user is a publicly accessed attribute. The value of level can not be edited by the user since it is being decided by the server. So, whenever a request is being made to a user profile (whether the user is logged in or not), you can simply check for the level using now() and the startTime stored in your database for that user profile. This will enable to get the current updated level of a user.

To make it a little bit simple, you can store the endTime instead of startTime in your database. endTime will store the time at which level will be upgraded.

Let's say, i am on level x. To reach level x+1, 24 hrs are required after the request for level upgrade is being made.

Store endTime as the sum of time at which request is called out + the time to be elapsed for level upgrade. Later you can simply check if now() >= endTime.

**The use case:**

Now, consider an example. I am an user and i initiated the request for level upgrade and i logged out from the application. Now, whoever access my profile will see my current updated level at that instant. This is solved.
But what if the rate of speed of the actions (e.g. gold mining) performed in the game depends upon the level of the user? In that case, suppose i did not login for next 2 days. But since my level should already be upgraded, the gold mining speed should become twice at the instant the level got upgraded.

To handle this scenario, there must be a server-side script which handles the activity for a user for time-based level upgrade.

You can implement a [cron job](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428) which can handle the updating of database in background.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon stated previously:

> The first is to build the time into the logic of the application. Set the level 2 time to the level 1 time plus one day. Then determine the level using now(). This has the downside that the logic can get complicated. But for a simple example such as your question, it might be the right choice.

His first option is probably the correct implementation choice and has a high performance factor. If implemented correctly, it should scale well.

To address your concern:

> So the main problem is that on the one hand I can update the database records if the user logs in by simply making a post request and updating the ellapsed trainings. But if the John doesn't login and Marc wants to see his level inside his profile, then there was no post request and it is showing up level 1 instead of level 2.

You would simply add business logic into your business logic tier that is executed whenever someone queries for John's profile. The business logic could simply evaluate the time remaining for the next level and if necessary show the corrected value. The logic could also potentially update John's record to indicate he has achieved the next level.

Comment: "But I also want to build a live database." -- Databases are an information storage/retrieval mechanism in general. Your application or game engine is what provides the "living" mechanism to update your database when "events" occur. It sounds like you are using stateless HTTP-based web services as a "game engine". Ultimately if you want to capture and manage real-time events then you need to use a stateful server application. HTTP servers in general only execute code when a client request is made.